# How do I update the object of an array list in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular6, angular2-forms

I have an array of JSON objects and displaying JSON keys in an angular chip. On click, I am able to get the data into the input field. Now, I want to update that object. How can I update? 
here is a sample of Array:

```js
datasource = [
"name1": {"id":28,"Title":"Sweden"}, 
"name2": {"id":56,"Title":"USA"}, 
"name3": {"id":89,"Title":"England"}
];
```

Comment: 1) that is invalid js, please provide a [mcve] 2) I have no idea what you are talking about, try to clarify your question according to [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming I understand correctly what you asked. Here's an example of a list of Items and an Input that changes an attribute of the object in the list. Angular handle this by itself.

[Example](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/0MAEWl55XKPVGSpv?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview). Just click at an item on the list and change the input value. When you click on an item, this item gets its reference set at the `selected` class attribute.